# Composition of functions is associative

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was reading the book on Abstract Algebra by Michael Artin. There I found a statement that said that composition of function if associative.

If T is a set and f,g ang h are three maps from T to T

$$T \xrightarrow{f} T \xrightarrow{g} T \xrightarrow{h} T$$

But this need not be generally true.

If T $\equiv$ set of all integers $\equiv \mathbb{Z}$

and for an element $x : x \in \mathbb{Z} $

$f(x)=x^2$

$g(x)=x+2$

$h(x)=2x$

$f(g(h(x)))=(2x+2)^2$

How do I verify associativity in this case?

How is the statement true?

Comment: You should recall what it means to be associative.

Comment: You're making confusion with commutativity. Associativity is something else.

Comment: Yeah I can see that now...but how is it associativite?

Comment: I edited the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just prove that $f \circ (g \circ h) = (f \circ g) \circ h$.

So take $x \in T$, and compute each of the above functions on $x$.
One gets
\begin{align}
(f \circ (g \circ h))(x) 
&= f((g\circ h)(x))\\
&= f(g(h(x)))\\
&= (f\circ g)(h(x))\\
&= ((f \circ g) \circ h)(x).
\end{align}

Comment: So basically m not changing the order

Comment: @Orpheus Right, you don't change the order, just change the grouping by parenthesis. I suppose you are acquainted with semigroups? The statement is that these function form a semigroup, under composition.